# Promise Chaining in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

My promise-then chain does not appear to wait for each previous return statement.

```
new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    console.log("1");
    const http = require('http');
    http.get(url, (resp) => {
        let data = '';
        resp.on('data', (chunk) => {
            data += chunk;
        });
        resp.on('end', () => {
            var info;
            // process data
            resolve(info);
        });

    }).on("error", (err) => {
        console.log("Error: " + err.message);
    });

}).then(function (info) { 
    console.log("2");
    if (info.item) {
        console.log("item exists, don't retry");
        return (info);
    }
    const http = require('http');
    http.get(url, (resp) => {
        let data = '';
        resp.on('data', (chunk) => {
            data += chunk;
        });
        resp.on('end', () => {
            var info;
            // process data
            return(info);
        });

    }).on("error", (err) => {
        console.log("Error: " + err.message);
    });
}).then(function (info) { 
    console.log("3");
    const http = require('http');
    http.get('otherurl' + info.item, (resp) => {
        let data = '';
        resp.on('data', (chunk) => {
            data += chunk;
        });
        resp.on('end', () => {
            console.log("processed");
            return (info);
        });

    }).on("error", (err) => {
        console.log("Error: " + err.message);
    });

}).then(function (info) {
    console.log("4 " + info);
});
```

I want my output to be, eg.:

> 1
>   2
>   3
>   processed
>   4 [someinfo]

Here is what I get:

> 1
>   2
>   3
>   4 undefined
>   processed

It appears that only the first promise-then happen asynchronously. Why aren't the second and third then statements waiting for the prior return?

Comment: I don't quite grasp what you are willing to do. For starters, `resolve` should be called only once.

Comment: I cant' see how you don't get an error that `resolve` isn't defined in the first .then ... and you are not returning anything from any .then (a return inside a callback in those .then is not returning from the .then - perhaps you really want to do something like https://jsfiddle.net/9frjdyqn/

Comment: Resolve is only called once, in the initial promise. Each then has a return. My goal to is call a URL. Sometimes that return is empty. In my first "then" I want to check if my call was successful. If not, I will retry the call. In the second "then" I will make a new call using a piece of data I got back from the first call.

Comment: you had a `resolve` inside the first .then until 3 minutes ago :p

Comment: still, you're not handling the second and third http.get like the first one, so, of course it won't work ... wrap them in individual `new Promise` like you did with the first - and return the new promise inside each .then - as per the fiddle

Comment: also, you only need `const http = require('http')` once, at the top of the code

Comment: "of course it won't work". Why do you think I'm here asking the question? If it were obvious to me, I wouldn't be here. Anyway, you have solved my problem by returning a new promise in each then statement. Thank you, I appreciate it.

Comment: In addition to the suggestions on the happy path, you are not handling errors in a very robust way. If something goes wrong, your promise will simply fizzle out without ever finishing. Consider invoking `reject` when an error occurs and make sure that consumers of this request chain think about proper error handling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code currently is:

```
new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    console.log("1");
    return(http.ClientRequest)

}).then(function (info) { 
    console.log("2");

    return(http.ClientRequest)

}).then(function (info) { 
    console.log("3");
    resolve(http.ClientRequest)

}).then(function (info) {
    console.log("4 " + info);
});
```

To work a Promise chain needs to `return` a promise from the `then` part. But anything you `return` from `then` is treated as promise. But in your case

1. You are not returning anything.
2. If you are returning, it is from the callback, so basically it doesn't go out of the function. if you do `return http.get(...)` you will get `http.ClientRequest` object in your next then chain. Not the actual data.

So in your case a crude way to do this will be: Promisifying each `http` call.

```
new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    console.log("1");
    const http = require('http');
    http.get(url, (resp) => {
        let data = '';
        resp.on('data', (chunk) => {
            data += chunk;
        });
        resp.on('end', () => {
            var info;
            // process data
            resolve(info);
        });

    }).on("error", (err) => {
        console.log("Error: " + err.message);
    });

}).then(function (info) {
    console.log("2");
    if (info.item) {
        console.log("item exists, don't retry");
        return (info);
    }
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        const http = require('http');
        http.get(url, (resp) => {
            let data = '';
            resp.on('data', (chunk) => {
                data += chunk;
            });
            resp.on('end', () => {
                var info;
                // process data
                resolve(info);
            });

        }).on("error", (err) => {
            console.log("Error: " + err.message);
        });
    })

}).then(function (info) {
    console.log("3");
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        const http = require('http');
        http.get('otherurl' + info.item, (resp) => {
            let data = '';
            resp.on('data', (chunk) => {
                data += chunk;
            });
            resp.on('end', () => {
                console.log("processed");
                resolve(info);
            });

        }).on("error", (err) => {
            console.log("Error: " + err.message);
        });
    })

}).then(function (info) {
    console.log("4 " + info);
});
```

**Note:** As I said it is a very non-elegant way of doing things, I would suggest using a promise based library like `axios` or maybe use `async` library instead of promises. Also you can use `async-await`. Each of them are better approach.

Comment: you're wrong, the code currently has only one resolve

Comment: Started to write the answer before the edit :) Editing the answer

Answer (score 1):

You are only resolving your first promise. 
When you return a value inside a callback you are not resolving the promise. 
You need to use the same strategy you use for the first one, wrapping the callback on a promise. So in your steps 2 and 3 you should return a new Promise and resolve it in the callback.

```
(...)
  .then(function(result){

    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){

      someThingWithCallback(result, function(err, data){
        resolve(data)
      })
    })
  })
  .then(function(data){
    ...
  })
```

You should try to avoid using a module that uses callbacks if you want to work with promises. You can use something like request-promise or axios.